# Loading external script into DOM at from rest call at runtime

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9

I'm trying to inject a html script into my Angular 9 app (from a 3rd party payment portal solution).

I have loaded the data into angular just fine (with a rest API call), and am doing this in component.ts to try to display it.

```
snippetData() {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.checkoutSnippet);
}
```

And this in the html template.

```
<div class="col-6" [innerHTML]="snippetData()"></div>
```

I can see that the content is updated accordingly in the DOM, see picture below.

[image]

The div with id "paysonContainer", and the outlined in green script get inserted from this script into the DOM.

The script however never loads, looking at the network tab in Firefox, it's simply not run.

What would I need to do to get the script to load?

Comment: Why are you loading the script at runtime instead of at build

Comment: Because it is generated from a 3rd party and could change at any time. I have no control of it, and I get the two html tags (script and div) returned as a string result of a "initiate checkout" call to their api.

Comment: Interesting. Seems like a pretty poor checkout provider and not particularly well suited to an angular app as this is a non angular anti pattern. Also you shouldn’t want the code in your app to change without your blessing as something could break. But don’t use a function to set the inner HTML. Just set the result to a property and set that.

Comment: I agree to it being less than ideal. But it's the best payment solution I have found that works with local payment methods in my country. I did try setting a result property as well, it diden't work, same result. I just tried the above code as a desperate attempt to see if it made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to append it dynamically in "head" tag.

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "http://somedomain.com/somescript";
var head = document.head;
head.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: This is in an angular2 (9) app, and I would prefer to stay within angular to solve the problem.

Comment: What's the problem of having js code inside angular app?

Comment: Angular2+ is typescript. mixing .js and .ts is dirty. Angular also has complete control of the DOM, so while it might be possible I doubt its good practice.

Comment: Try it first and if it works, we will find the best practice from there.

Comment: This whole thing isn’t good practice and typescript compiles to JavaScript no matter what. Browsers don’t run typescript